# How to find the solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$ E'(x) = \alpha(E_m - E(x)) \ \ \ \ \text{(α is a positive constant)
> } $$

Determine *E(x)* with $E(0) = E_0 < E_m$.

This is supposed to be solved as a differential equation.  However, I am not sure how to go about solving the problem.  Assistance in finding the solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$E' = \alpha(E_{m}-E) \implies \int \frac{dE}{(E_{m}-E)} = \alpha \int dx$$ and hopefully you can recognise the solution to the integral on the LHS is in terms of a logarithm.

Comment: @mattos Thank you for your reply.  What does  ∫  equal/how do I solve this part?

Comment: $$\alpha \int dx = \alpha x + C$$ I think you need to revise integration.